# mkp224o v3 onion link get overwritten by tor

Tags: onion-services, onion-routing

Firstly, I'm using windows.I created the hostname, secret key and public key on windows. When I changed it, tor rewrites it every time I reopen tor.

i replaced these 3 files with the keys i got from mkp224o.After that, when i try to change permissions tor doesn't work and gives this error.

Error: “Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start.”

I tried these codes in my torrc file:

The change I made to my torrc file :

HiddenServiceDir C:\Users\Casper\Documents\Tor Browser\deneme

HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

sudo chown -R tor: C:\Users\Casper\Documents\Tor Browser\deneme

sudo chmod -R u+rwX,og-rwx C:\Users\Casper\Documents\Tor Browser\deneme

Also, I get the same error when I change permissions from properties in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is in wrong format because the changes you've made are actually correct. Also make sure that you're generating Onion v3 keys, not an older ones